# Trying to understand the theory behind my similar / better results than XGBoost using a calibrated linear model (GAM)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-comparison, constrained-optimization

I just opened a [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/15lscuq/d_getting_similar_or_better_results_than_xgboost/) asking about why/how the calibrated linear models I've been training have been getting similar / better results than XGBoost in my experiments. I was told to cross post here with my question to field some answers from seasoned statisticians.

Calibrated linear models have the following form:

```
f(x) = b + a_1 * c_1(x_1) + ... + a_n * c_n(x_n)
```

We have the linear combination (with optional bias) of the calibrated values where each calibrator is a piece-wise linear function (for numerical features) or a 1:1 mapping (for categorical features). The calibrators are learned along with the rest of the network via SGD. [This paper](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume17/15-243/15-243.pdf) section 7 talks about calibrators in more detail.

My understanding is that these calibrated linear models are a form of GAM, but I'm hoping to better understand why I'm able to get these results even without more complex feature crossing.

A bonus of these calibrated models is that you can constrain the linear coefficients as well as the shape of individual calibrators to easily guarantee certain shape constraints (e.g. monotonicity). However, I didn't use any constraints in my experiments.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Are you modeling categorical outcomes (“classification”) or numerical?

Comment: I've been modeling mostly binary classification tasks.